# ActionScript3 - augmenting prototype of String

Tags: string, actionscript-3, prototype

In AS2 I could do the following:

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(s){
     return this.indexOf(s) == 1
}
```

thus, `startsWith` is available on every String object

```
var s = "some string to test with";
s.startsWith("some") // returns true
```

and did it with great repository of cool tools:

```
var s = "some @VAR string";
s.startsWith("some");//returns true
s.endsWith("ing");//returns true
s.contains("@");//returns true
s.dataBind({VAR: "awsome"})// returns 'some awsome string'
s = "b";
s.isAnyOf("a","b","c"); //true, because "b" is one of the options
s.isInArr(["a","b","c"]); //true, because "b" is in the passed array
var o = { foo: function(i) { return "wind " + i } }
s = "foo";
f.call(o,3) //returns "wind 3" because method foo is ivoked on o with 3
f.apply(o,[3]) //returns "wind 3" because method foo is ivoked on o with 3
var a1 = [], a2 = []
s.push(a1,a2) // pushes s into a1 and a2
```

And so on, and so forth with many cool things that makes coding much more fun (and blazing fast when smartly used)

It's not just about String, I have such utils for Number, Date, Boolean, and so on.

Here's what I tried:

```
[Test]
public function test_stringPrototype()
{
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(s):Boolean
    {
        return return this.indexOf(s) == 1;
    }

    assertTrue( !!String.prototype.startsWith ) //and so far - so good ! this line passes

    var s:String = "some str";
    assertTrue(!!o.startsWith ) //and this won't even compile... :(
}
```

And this won't even compile, not to mention pass or fail the test...
error: `Access of possibly undefined property startsWith through a reference with static type String.`

Whats the way to do it in AS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, use string representation of a variable name: "startsWith"; Example down

```
        String.prototype.traceME = function():void
        {
            trace(this);
        }

        var s:String = "some str";
        s["traceME"]();
```

else method:

```
            var s:Object = new String("some str");
            s.traceME();
```

Comment: It worked, though it makes the code so much less elegant... beside these utils, here is what I try to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882430/how-would-object-defineproperty-be-in-as3

Comment: But you know what? the question is the ["..."] trick is just to fool the IDE and drop the precompilation warnings...

Comment: yes, you right, now i read post from you link, and i think about it: var s:Object = new String("some str"); s.startsWith();  and trick the precompilation warnings

Comment: is there a way to explain the IDE to let it go?

Answer (score 1):

you could always have the utility class that will collect all those methods and work on the string, e.g.

```
package utils
{
    public class StringUtils
    {
        public static function startsWith(input:String, test:String):Boolean
        {
            return input.indexOf(test) == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
trace(StringUtils.startWith("My string", "My"));
```

or as a "global" function:

```
package utils
{
    public function startsWith(input:String, test:String):Boolean
    {
        return input.indexOf(test) == 0;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
trace(startWith("My string", "My"));
```

best regards

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. Makes coding combersome. If wanted to use static utils I'd program C